# transparent menu / css

Tags: html, css

I am working on a transparent menu for my site.This is my current code

```
nav{
display: inline-block;
position:overlay;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:80px;
padding: 10px 90px;
box-sizing: border-box;
background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

[image]

I want the menu to be transparent like this site
https://www.holeman-finch.com.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `background-color:transparent`

Comment: small comment (not related): `position: overlay` is not valid CSS, check the possible values here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Thanks for the position to absolute fixed the problem.Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
nav{
display: inline-block;
position:overlay;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:80px;
padding: 10px 90px;
box-sizing: border-box;
background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
margin-bottom:-80px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nav{
display: inline-block;
position: overlay;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:80px;
padding: 10px 90px;
box-sizing: border-box;
background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your header element, you can use any transparent background color, for example a very light white transparent shade which will work fine as an overlay on a darker photo:

```
background-color: #ffffff42;
```

In order for your header to actually float on top of the photo behind it, add `position: fixed;` or `position: sticky;` to it, for example. The same effect can also be achieved with `position: absolute;` and some extra `top`, `right` and `left` properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
nav {
  max-width: 960px;
  /* The mask-image gives us some extra fading. It is not necessary but without this, you can't face out the box-shadows. This clips our menu */
  mask-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, #ffffff 25%, #ffffff 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Using padding instead of margin for the top and bottom here will keep our box-shadow visible and not affected by the mask-image */
  padding: 75px 0;
}

nav ul {
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  font-size: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
```